# Return boolean indicator if row value is contained in a column of a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column full of identifiers

```
df1.['ID1']
    aaa
    aab
    aac
    ...
    zzx
    zzy
    zzz
```

And another column in a separate dataframe with identifiers that are contained in the ID1 column

```
df2.['ID2']
    aab
    ...
    zzy
```

I need to add a column to df1 that indicates whether or not the identifier in each row is contained in the column in df2. So something like this:

```
df1.['shared']
aaa   False
aab   True
aac   False
...
zzx   False
zzy   True
zzz   False
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Use `df.isin`:

```
In [233]: df
Out[233]: 
  Col1
0  aaa
1  aab
2  aac
3  zzx
4  zzy
5  zzz

In [234]: df2
Out[234]: 
  Col2
0  aab
1  zzy

In [235]: df.Col1.isin(df2.Col2)
Out[235]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

---

**Option 2**

You can use `np.in1d`:

```
In [344]: pd.Series(np.in1d(df.Col1, df2.Col2), name='Col1')
Out[344]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Col1, dtype: bool
```

Timings:

```
In [245]: len(df_test)
Out[245]: 60000

In [246]: %timeit df_test.Col1.isin(df2.Col2)  # in this post
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [247]: %timeit df_test.Col1.apply(lambda x: x in df2.Col2) # df.apply solution
1 loop, best of 3: 601 ms per loop

In [349]: %timeit pd.Series(np.in1d(df_test.Col1, df2.Col2), name='Col1')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: isin is the way to go. Could also throw in np.in1d

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['shared'] = df1.ID1.apply(lambda x: x in df2.ID2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try `map`

```
df2['Bool']=True
df2.index=df2.Col2
df1.Col1.map(df2.Bool).fillna(False)

Out[239]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
```